# Photoshop: Edit->Automate->Photomerge… mis-aligned focus-stack

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When trying to use Photomerge for focus-stacking, Photoshop will displace several layers, rather than correctly aligning & calculating the mask.

I think the image says everything
[image: ,]

Comment: I believe Photomerge is for merging smaller fragments into a large image. Like a panorama image. Perhaps you should try using *File > Script > Load Files into Stack*?

Comment: @Wolff - Photomerge set to auto is the regular start-point for focus-stacking, which appears to be what the OP is trying to do. It's not perfect & it's not as good at it as dedicated stacking software, but 'mainly it works, sort of';) I used to do a lot of stacking with Ps but have since moved on to better software for this particular task. 'Load files into stack' doesn't attempt to make a focus-stack, it just plonks all the images one above the other.

Comment: I've attempted to back-fill the question to describe in words what the image appears to convey. I hope I've not strayed too far from the OP's intent.

Comment: @Tetsujin, OK thanks for explaining. I wasn't aware that Photomerge was supposed to be able to do focus stacking. Never had much luck using it for anything really.

Comment: You need a good tutorial. There's one here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=QyMGIMhbLyk&feature=emb_logo - it doesn't use Photomerge

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop does that if you're trying to focus stack & it can't figure out where one image is supposed to fit; it drops it out away from the rest of the stack. It most often does this if you were shooting handheld so your framing varies too much, or right at the ends of your focus pull, as you get to the images being mainly out of focus with only one or two sharp sections. Occasionally if your slices are too far apart so it can't find similar detail in consecutive images [we can see it's a strawberry, Photoshop's not that smart ;)
I've found, empirically, that if it really doesn't want to stack them, even if you force it it won't do a very good job.

Sometimes you can work without that one layer. Alternatively, you have to manually crop & straighten the aberrant layer by hand & see if you can persuade it to stack. Best alternative [but not free] is to use something like Affinity Photo or Zerene Stacker instead.

Photoshop's problem is that it only likes high contrast edges. if you give it low contrast or large areas with similar colour, it just fails to spot the sharpest points [& will go as far as the OP's issue where it just can't figure it out at all.]

Just as an example I ran an image I'd already previously done in Affinity instead passed through Photmerge at defaults. This would require a lot of manual clean-up. As you can see from even just this screen-shot, it has clearly failed to differentiate most of the large yellow area towards the front of the image & it's really just a mess.
<sub>Click for larger sizes. Neither image is at full resolution, both shrunk.</sub>

[image]

This is the finished version from Affinity [polished in Ps, of course, not just right out of the stacker] but the stacking was done just at defaults. I find that I very rarely have to do anything more than 'auto' so long as my initial photography was up to scratch.

[image]